# MinGW Forward dll call

Tags: c++, c, dll, call

I'm trying to forward calls from my DLL to another DLL. I can't find any documentation about how to do that with MinGW.

Using Visual C++ compiler I would go with:

```
#pragma comment (linker, "/export:DllInitialize=api.DllInitialize,@2")
```

Or by using a .def definition file:

```
EXPORTS

DllInitialize=api.DllInitialize
```

But none of these work when compiling with MinGW32. I am using Code::Blocks as IDE if it matters. How can I do this with MinGW32?

Answer (score 1):

i am sorry, i added a bit too many double-quotes in the above code. instead it should be this way:

```
asm (".section .drectve\n\t.ascii \" -export:DllInitialize=api.DllInitialize @2\"");
```

If you need to use it many times, consider putting it in a macro, e.g.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define FORWARDED_EXPORT_WITH_ORDINAL(exp_name, ordinal, target_name) __pragma (comment (linker, "/export:" #exp_name "=" #target_name ",@" #ordinal))
#endif
#ifdef __GNUC__
    #define FORWARDED_EXPORT_WITH_ORDINAL(exp_name, ordinal, target_name) asm (".section .drectve\n\t.ascii \" -export:" #exp_name "= " #target_name " @" #ordinal "\"");
#endif

FORWARDED_EXPORT_WITH_ORDINAL(DllInitialize, 2, api.DllInitialize)
FORWARDED_EXPORT_WITH_ORDINAL(my_create_file_a, 100, kernel32.CreateFileA)
```

you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #pragma comment (linker, "/export:DllInitialize=api.DllInitialize,@2")
#endif
#ifdef __GNUC__
    asm (".section .drectve\n\t.ascii \" -export:\\\"DllInitialize=api.DllInitialize\\\" @2\"");
#endif
```

Note that "drectve" is not a typo, thats how it must be written however odd it may seem. By the way, this strange abbreviation is a microsoft's idea, not GCC's.